# How can i execute multiple commands with JAVA code?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I need to restart my Tomcat server from Java code. I'm a beginner in Java. I try to do that by cmd. I need to stop tomcat then restart it. I try this code. It works with just two commands (one &&) and it doesn't work if I add a third command (two && in the line `exec("cmd /c start cmd.exe ...)`).

PS: If another way exists to restart Tomcat with Java code please tell me

```java
public class restart_tomcat {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SDKException, IOException {
        Runtime rt =  Runtime.getRuntime();

        try {
            // Process process1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start cmd.exe /K " + cmd1);
            rt.exec("cmd /c start cmd.exe /K \"cd C:\\\\Program Files (x86)\\\\SAP BusinessObjects\\\\tomcat\\\\bin&&startup.bat\"");
            System.out.println("succesful");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *”i need to restart my tomcat server from java code”* - I seriously doubt that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be good to know why do you need to start/stop Tomcat from java code, is that a homework or something else? In the real-world, we have initialization scripts that can start/stop it by simply running them from the terminal. You can automate that with a very simple shell script (yourscript.sh) and add the following content:

```
#!/bin/bash
<path_to_tomcat>/bin/shutdown.sh
<path_to_tomcat>/bin/startup.sh
```

If you really need to do it from Java code, you may find your answer in one of these resources:

- [Start and Stop Tomcat from java code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21321897/start-and-stop-tomcat-from-java-code)
- [Restart Tomcat with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48109709/restart-tomcat-with-java)
- [Start and Stop Tomcat from java code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21321897/start-and-stop-tomcat-from-java-code)
- [How to start Tomcat Server programmatically in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24929175/how-to-start-tomcat-server-programmatically-in-java)
- [how to restart tomcat from a running webapp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11874789/how-to-restart-tomcat-from-a-running-webapp)

Comment: Or something like supervisord.

Comment: It is not a homework, in fact i need to restart tomcat in the last step  of my script in my project , means after some code, the Tomcat gonna be restarted from Eclipse . i tried the solution in the link but doesn't work.

Comment: just updated the answer @bahrinada. Could you take a look at new resources?

Comment: yeah i do, in fact i restart tomcat with java code throught the cmd, thanx to @DanielVilas-Boas for the idea ;)